# How to change the tabbar's tab at run time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableview in which, in the first row, I am trying to initially add a static value to the detailtextlabel. So when the tableview is loaded initially, the detailtextlabel shows the default value. When I click on the detailtextlabel, it switches. I have added code that will switch the default value to another value. This is working properly.
This is my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            if ([cell.detailTextLabel.text isEqualToString:@"digital"]) {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"analog";
                userdefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                [userdefaults setObject:@"analog" forKey:@"clock"];
            }
            else {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"digital";
                [userdefaults setObject:@"digital" forKey:@"clock"];
            }
            [userdefaults synchronize];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But my problem is when the label is getting changed from digital to analog, the digital view controller, which is added as the first tab in the mainwindow, should get changed to an analog viewcontroller and when analog is changed to digital, the digital viewcontroller should be replaced by the analog view controller in the first tab.

//In the appdidfinish launching I have done this code, but it does not change the tabbar at runtime.

```
NSString *clockswitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"clock"];
if ([clockswitch isEqualToString:@"digital"]) {
    DigitalClockViewController *dig = [[DigitalClockViewController alloc]init];
    //self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
else
{
    AnalogClockViewController *ana = [[AnalogClockViewController alloc]init];
    //self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.ana objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Can't you just set the active controller by self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = digitalClockControllerIndex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UITabBarController.viewControllers is an immutable array you need to make a mutable copy.

NSString *clockswitch = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"clock"];
UIViewController *desiredController = nil;
if ([clockswitch isEqualToString:@"digital"]) {
    desiredController = [[DigitalClockViewController alloc]init];
}
else {
    desiredController = [[AnalogClockViewController alloc]init];
}
NSMutableArray *controllersCopy = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];
[controllersCopy replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:desiredController];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllersCopy;
```

Comment: That makes sense, your running the code in applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions: which is only called, well when it sounds like when the application finishes launching.  You could pick a logical class perhaps your delegate perhaps the rootViewController and set it as the tabBarDelegate, and when it calls -tabBar:didSelectItem: you can check (if that tab was selected) that the viewController at that index is of the correct class.

Comment: hi @Njones that got worked . i have added  your code in the delegate method of tabbarcontroller i.e tabbarController didSelectViewController

Comment: i am having a doubt i want to give a default value to my detailtext label i.e by default digital should be displayed in the detailtextlabel and in the  tab also by default digitalcontroller should be shown

Comment: hi @Njones , problem of view switching on a tabbar is solved ,but i have  a problem that initially when i run my app in the first tab navigation bar is visible.But when i change the label of the detailtext ans switch to the first tab the navigation bar is not visible.Please help me in solving my prob.Thanks

Comment: This seems like a separate question. But, do you mean when the tab says digital there's no navBar or when the tab says analog there's no navBar, or both? Again sort of a separate question hard to answer without code.

Comment: when the tab says analog there is  no navBar

Comment: Will it come back if you switch to digital? If so check your view controller classes for any difference. Also nibs if you are using interface builder.